# What method to Login Customer Without Password in Magento 1.9?

Tags: php, html, authentication, magento

I want customers login with their email id only. Is any way to skip password in magento 1.9.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code :

```
$email = 'example@email.com';
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
$customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
$customer->loadByEmail(trim($email));
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->loginById($customer->getId());
```

Comment: HI @Belayet Hossen Riad thanks, this works for outside of magento. I need within it.